# Jquery html with audio slideshow

Tags: jquery, audio, slideshow

I need to get a jquery html slideshow where each html content is having an audio content.

Each slide having a audio file.which plays when that slide is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If not a exact solution I am sure you might atleast find some useful articles with this **[Google search](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_nf=1&cp=17&gs_id=1u&xhr=t&q=jquery%20audio%20slideshow&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=jquery%20audio%20slid&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=ad95e93aa7df556d&biw=1024&bih=679)**.

Comment: I already viewed these plugins.It is only having one audio file which will be playing slideshow background.I need to play audio for all slides.

Comment: @tomjoy Ok I did not know that it plays only one file for all slides.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to combine all the audio clips into a single audio file using a tool like audacity you could use the HTML 5 player that Soundslides has.

http://soundslides.com